# How to store data in MongoDB using Java driver

Tags: json, mongodb-java, bson

To mongoDB a Java program I want to store the data of Json description.

Previous (MongoDB 3.0 use the DB class of previous non-recommended), in the code, such as the (program 1)
It had can be stored in MongoDB to convert a string of Json type DBObject type.
(program 1）

```
DBCollection coll；
String doc=”{\”math\" : \"77\”}”;
DB db;
DBCollection coll;
db = m.getDB("dbMongo10");
coll = db.getCollection("collectionMongo10");
DBObject json = (DBObject) JSON.parse(doc);                             
coll.insert(json);
```

But now (use the DB class of recommendation from MongoDB 3.0), and either not be able to insert as it is the Json string
It has, but I can not.(
program 3,4,5,6)

However Document type of data was able to insert.
(program 2)

```
MongoClient m = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = m.getDatabase("dbMongo10");
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("collectionMongo10");
Document doc = new Document("math","75");
coll.insertOne(doc);
```

It'not work.
(program 3)

```
String json = "{\"math\" : \"77\"}";
coll.insertOne(json);
```

(program 4)

```
String json = "{\"math\" : \"77\"}";
BSONObject bson = (BSONObject)com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(json);
coll.insertOne(bson);
```

(program 5)

```
String json = "{\"math\" : \"77\"}";
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);
String json1 = JSON.serialize( dbObject );
DBObject bson = ( DBObject ) JSON.parse( json1 );
coll.insertOne(bson);
```

(program 6)

```
String json = "{\"math\" : \"77\"}";
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document saveDocument = (Document) builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(json)));
```

Json format string or will not be as it is to be stored in a DB.
If it can not, please tell me how to program that it is to be stored the storing at Bson format.

Comment: coll.insertOne(document);

Comment: String json = "{\"math\" : \"77\"}";
        Document document = Document.parse(json);

Comment: thank you.
 With next program I can work .
  
    
        String json = "{\"math\" : \"77\"}";
        Document document = Document.parse(json);
 coll.insertOne(document);